# Minify Child and Parent CSS WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, minify

If I manually minify the CSS of a parent WordPress theme, should I also minify the child theme CSS?

I don't use plugins for minifying CSS or plugins such as W3 Total Cache to minify. I've had bad luck with these.

This is in my child theme:

```
function func_enqueue_child_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css'   );
```

I am assuming wp_enqueue will fold the child CSS into the parent style sheet meaning if I don't minify the child, the combined style sheet will be only partially minified. Does anyone know if this is correct?

Comment: Have a look on [Code Reference - wp_enqueue_style()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/).

Comment: Why would you want to minify the CSS file *manually?* it makes making changes later on pretty *difficult*. Plugins that minify CSS files do so to the file version that gets sent to the user's browser. You still maintain the ability to edit the CSS file with ease later on. If you minify the files *manually* you lose that ability. You can still edit them but minifing will strip all readability away.

Comment: I can minify a style sheet within WP in only a minute or two. I can also edit by using a master copy and then re-minify. Pretty simple. I hear ya, however I have had bad luck with plugins.